# Picture does not show in imageview

Tags: android, camera

I am opening camera on button click and taking picture and showing it in imageview. It's working in Google Nexus. But it's not working in Samsung Tab and Micromax canvas HD,Why?

My Button click code :

```
       CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 100;

     String path =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/MySampleApp/image.jpg";

            File file = new File(path);
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

OnActivityResult code :

```
         BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
              Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,
                            options);
                    mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Permissions in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Why is this code not working in samsung and micromax?

This is the correct code are not?

Any one please help me?

Comment: Are you getting any log in logcat while deploying your app on Samsung Tab and Micromax canvas HD ?

Comment: yes,Error reading file from SDCard in android this error i am getting

Comment: Is bug solved or not ? As you accepted one answer...

Comment: Yeah,my problem Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 100;
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);   
            }
        });
```

And

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {   
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
      Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
      mImageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it will work in micromax devices..use this uri

```
btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    pop.dismiss();
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), StaticMembers.galleryRequestCode);
                }
            });
            ImageView btnCamera = (ImageView) pop.findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
            btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

                    //With Camera Utils
                    pop.dismiss();
                    outpuUri = CameraUtil.startCam(yourActivity.this);
                }
            });


@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        Log.d("Alpha", "onActivity : " + requestCode);
        System.gc();
        Log.d("Alpha", "onActivity : " + requestCode + " RESULT CODE : " + resultCode);
        System.gc();
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
        String time = timestamp + "";
        String imgPath = null;

        if (requestCode == CameraUtil.IMAGE_CAPTURED && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            if (outpuUri != null)
            {
                Log.d("Alpha", "URI NOT NULL");
                imgPath = outpuUri.getPath();
                //Log.d("Alpha", "ACT RES PATH : " + imgPath);
                //mCapturedBitmap = CameraUtil.sampleBitmap(imgPath, ivHeightWidth);
                //iv.setImageBitmap(mCapturedBitmap);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("Alpha", "URI NULL IN CAM");
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == StaticMembers.galleryRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            outpuUri = data.getData();
            imgPath = getPath(outpuUri);
            mCapturedBitmap = CameraUtil.sampleBitmap(imgPath, ivHeightWidth);// BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
            iv.setImageBitmap(mCapturedBitmap);
            Log.d("Alpha", "In Gallery " + imgPath);
        }
        if (imgPath != null)
        {
            showConfrirmDialog(imgPath, time);
        }

    }



    public class CameraUtil
    {

        private static Uri outpuUri;

        public static final int IMAGE_CAPTURED = 200;

        public static String imageName;

        private static String imageFolder;


        public static Uri startCam(Activity context)
        {
            imageName = "sample" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            outpuUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImageFolderFile().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + imageName));
            Log.d("CHECK", "BEFORE STARTING CAM URI : " + outpuUri.getPath());
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outpuUri);
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
            context.startActivityForResult(i, IMAGE_CAPTURED);
            return outpuUri;
        }


        public static File getImageFolderFile()
        {

            imageFolder = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "sparkchat_camera_pics";

            File f = new File(imageFolder);
            Log.d("Alpha", f.getAbsolutePath() + " exists > " + f.exists());
            if (!f.exists())
                f.mkdirs();
            return f;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this code is not working..Image was stored in sdcard,but when i am click on image in sdcard it show me a toast could't find item.